# LinkedList Stack Structure Big O

Tags: linked-list, stack, big-o, singly-linked-list

The answer for the following question is O(n) for pop and O(1) for push. But i don't quite understand why pop cannot be O(1). We do have tail pointer pointing to the end of the linkedlist and we are supposed to access it in O(1) time right? Did i miss anything here?

What is the running time of the **push** and **pop** operations if the bottom of the Stack must be at the head of the linked memory structure? where n is the number of nodes in the structure.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about the invariants of your stack: `tail` points to the last element.

The **pop** operation removes the last element — this means we need to re-adjust `tail`. How do we do this? With a doubly-linked list we could just follow the pointer back to the previous node — but as your illustration clearly shows, there is no such arrow back to the previous node in a singly-linked list.

So instead we need to start at `head` (the only other node for which we hold a pointer), and iterate all the way until we arrive at the second-to-last node, and then set `tail` to point to that node.

Comment: Thank you! I forget there is a tail to reset.